# Differences between redeploy and undeploy in Glassfish

Tags: java, unix, glassfish

I stumbled onto something I just want to understand. I had trouble undeploying an application in Glassfish 4.1. Using the GUI, I selected the app in the list and clicked on "undeploy", but the app stayed in the list. Restarting GF did not help.

For some reason I finally clicked on "redeploy" directly in the list. The app failed to deploy, but undeploying worked, it disappeared from the list. After another GF restart I could deploy the app again, and everything was fine.

My question is: Why did undeploy not work, but redeploy succeeded in at least undeploying the stubborn app? Does redeploy do some kind of 'force undeploy'?
Thanks guys :)

Comment: You should be referring to the logs.

Comment: The logs just told me of a problem deploying the app, for some security reason. They did not explain why redeploy worked, kinda, where undeploy did not.

Comment: I actually just rescanned the logs. There is no indication as to why the UNdeploy would not work. On restarting GF, the app complains about a Security Exception (I guess when trying to start the app), but nothing else.... But again. I got it working, I just want to know the difference between redeploy and undeploy, if any.

Comment: Undeploy undeploys the application, redeploy just deploys it on the old one. There's nothing magical about them, but if undeploy fails it can mean a resource leak or a similar problem.